# Adding a list of elements to a linked list

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, linked-list

I'm developing an android application with google maps.
I have created a hashmap which stores Lat/Lng,Float in it.

```
Map<LatLng,Float> distance_Map = new HashMap<LatLng, Float>();
```

I use this to store distance between 2 given latitude and longitude using following method.

```
Location loc1 = new Location("");
        loc1.setLatitude(markerPoints.get(0).latitude);
        loc1.setLongitude(markerPoints.get(0).longitude);

        Location loc2 = new Location("");
        loc2.setLatitude(markerPoints.get(i).latitude);
        loc2.setLongitude(markerPoints.get(i).longitude);

        float distance = loc1.distanceTo(loc2);

        distance_Map.put(markerPoints.get(i), distance);
```

So I run this code through a loop and find distances between the first place user enters and the other places and stores the corresponding distances and Lng/Lat in the distance_Map.After that I use the following code to sort these distances.

```
List<Map.Entry<LatLng,Float>> sorted_Distance_LatLng_List = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<LatLng, Float>>(distance_Map.entrySet());
            Collections.sort(sorted_Distance_LatLng_List, new Comparator<Map.Entry<LatLng, Float>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Map.Entry<LatLng, Float> o1, Map.Entry<LatLng, Float> o2) {
                    return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());

                }
            });
```

This runs perfectly.But I need to use the same linkedlist sorted_Distance_LatLng_List to sort another set of distances.To do that I use the same hashmap (distance_Map) by clearing its values.

```
distance_Map.clear();
distance_Map.put(markerPoints.get(i), distance);
```

but I do not know how to insert this distance_Map to the same LinkedList(sorted_Distance_LatLng_List).I use the following code

```
sorted_Distance_LatLng_List.clear();

                List<Map.Entry<LatLng,Float>> sorted_Distance_LatLng_List = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<LatLng, Float>>(distance_Map.entrySet());
                Collections.sort(sorted_Distance_LatLng_List, new Comparator<Map.Entry<LatLng, Float>>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Map.Entry<LatLng, Float> t1, Map.Entry<LatLng, Float> t2) {
                        return t1.getValue().compareTo(t2.getValue());
                    }
                });
```

But it gives me the error, because the list is already created. How can I do it?Please help me.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As the list is already created, you don't need to create it again. Second time, you just assign the value to it.
If you remove `List<Map.Entry<LatLng,Float>>` from the second code, the error will go away.